# Замена с помощью regexp

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Простое задание: заменить дату в формате "дд.мм.гггг" на "дд месяц гггг"
На Perl это сделал быстро, но надо на C++.

```
std::string date = "12.10.2017";
std::regex monthSE(R"((?=\.)\d\d(?=\.))");
std::vector<std::string> months = {
    "", "января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня",
    "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"};
std::smatch matched;
std::regex_search(date, matched, monthSE);
if (!matched.size())
{
    break;
}
std::string asd = matched[0].str();
int month = atoi(matched[0].str().c_str());
std::regex monthRE(R"(\.\d\d\.)");
date = std::regex_replace(date, monthRE, " " + months[month] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

А нужно ли из пушки по воробьям? Если формат известен строго - `"дд.мм.гггг"` - то вполне хватит тривиального

```
vector<string> months = {
    "", " января ", " февраля ", " марта ", " апреля ", " мая ", " июня ",
    " июля ", " августа ", " сентября ", " октября ", " ноября ", " декабря "};

string date(string d)
{
    return d.replace(2,4,months[stoi(d.substr(3,2))]);
}


int main()
{
    cout << date("12.04.1961") << endl;
    cout << date("19.05.1963") << endl;
}
```